# In the Pern series, what are the "zebeedees"?

Tags: pern

Readers of *All The Weyrs Of Pern* will know that Aivas named the "springs" found in dissected samples of Thread ovoids "zebeedees".

Which obviously is "ZBD"s.

So in our scientific world, what is a "ZBD"?  IOW, what does that acronym represent?

Comment: I think it was mentioned during the first fall of thread that they were classified as a zoonotic biological disease (hence ZBD) or something similar. I would need to check the books for the passage to confirm though.

Comment: I've checked the book, the name is spelled "zebedee" with one less "e". I've checked the biblical character with the same name, but there is no connection to springs or diseases, so it's probably just a coincidence. The word is Italian slang for a part of the male anatomy that is distinctly ovoidal, but this is *certainly* a coincidence :-)

Comment: @Vorbis - sorry I got the spelling wrong - but actually I don't think it's that important - ijust as with "agenothree" it is (IMO!) meant to be the modern Pernese interpretation of a word AIVAS is using that they don't understand is an acronym.  But see A.B.'s answer below for another interpretation.  I totally agree that the bibilical name has no connection.

Comment: It's not an acronym, it's a gift from god.

Comment: @Tragamor - I can look for that! Thanks!  And I suppose it is possible that given the name Zebedee as per A.B.'s answer she crafted that phrase to match it ...

Comment: I just assumed that it was AIVAS's sense of humour

Comment: I had a look through the majority of the Pern books last night including First Fall, which is what I thought it was in with no luck. It's certainly possible in my youth I may have ascribed some terminology myself to it....

Comment: Sure they will. Are you suggesting Norton said AIVAS named the "springs" found in dissected samples of Thread ovoids "zebeedees" by chance, or because "zebeedees" or "ZBD" meant something and if so, what?

Answer (score 33):

In this case, possibly not.  Pern does seem to do a lot of that words-that-are-derived-from-acronyms thing, but this may not be one of them.  "Zebedee" was the name of a character in the kids' TV show *[The Magic Roundabout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Roundabout)*, that hopped about on a spring.

[image]

(It doesn't seem likely that the characters in the main sequence would know that, hundreds of years and considerable information loss later, but AIVAS presumably got this name from one of the early colonists, who were far enough back that they might remember what Zebedee was - or at least that he had something to do with springs).

Comment: That's .... not bad!  AIVAS had a really complete cultural library ... assuming of course they're in the same universe as we are, or one that's close enough!  (AIVAS and the Pern people used other acronyms, as you say, e.g., HNO3 = "agenothree", that's why I went in that direction.)

Comment: *"AIVAS presumably got this name from one of the early colonists, who were far enough back that they might remember what Zebedee was"* - Well reasoned!

Comment: I was gonna pooh-pooh this idea, since the author was American while the show was British, but it appears that half the time that show was on the air she was living in Dublin, with young children in the house. I don't know how available the BBC was to Irish viewers in the 1970's, but it seems plausible?

Comment: *Magic Roundabout* was a hugely popular show in it's day, and McCaffrey would definitely have known about it if she had kids of the right age in Dublin. Time for bed...

Comment: Further looked into it, and McCaffery had [a professional science advisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Cohen_(biologist)) for the Pern series who was a trained biologist and was British. It seems quite likely the details of the biological design of the Zebedees was largely his, and he'd certainly have had access to the BBC while that show was running.

Comment: To add a few dates: *All the Weyrs of Pern* was published in 1991.  McCaffrey moved to Ireland in 1970, and as far as I can find made her home there for the rest of her life.  The Magic Roundabout originally aired 1965–1977; but at least in the UK, it remained current enough that as a child born in 1982, I and my peers growing up in the 80s and 90s were all familiar with it (either through re-airing or on video).  I can’t find details on whether/when it was shown in Ireland, but lots of British shows were.

Comment: As a child born in 1983, I also remember enjoying it on video.

Comment: It was absolutely possible to see this in Ireland in that time period.

Comment: As something of a supporting basis for their using a Magic Roundabout reference in universe, consider that the naming conventions of the colonists are saturated with Earth geography references of the same era.  That even without AIVAS quoting Psalms in the Ninth pass.  Cultural memes maintaining awareness seems just fine.  I think there's an explicit call out about old Earth name use in Dragon's Dawn or First Fall?

Comment: though cultural awareness of the _Bible_ or major Earth cities/countries/events is a _bit_ more likely than a random ancient children's TV show, wouldn't you think?

Answer (score 10):

Likely it was a reference to the Zinc Binding Domain (or Zinc-finger Binding Domain).

"[Zinc fingers](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Zinc_finger)" are a class of protein chunks which show up all over the place. They have twisty, spiraling forms, and were getting written up in the late 80s (i.e. while *Weyrs* was being written). [Example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022283689900077).

One major place they show up is in [transcription factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_factor). DNA has segments that various proteins attach to. Zinc finger domains, are regions on the protein (protein domains) that are represented like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA-binding_domain#/media/File:Transcription_factors_DNA_binding_sites.svg) (link to wiki for image; not sure about license compatibility) and which allow the protein to attach to whatever it needs to attach to, DNA for example.

Comment: Very nice!  Never heard of those.

Comment: @davidbak I tried to read up a little as part of writing this, and they make my head spin.

Comment: You got farther than me.  I just looked at the interesting diagrams ...

Comment: While zinc finger domains are indeed very well known in the field of biology, I doubt they could be behind this name. The "twisty spiraling" forms in your image is actually DNA that the ZN proteins are binding to, and not the ZN proteins themselves. And although proteins do indeed have spiral regions, they don't really look like springs and the whole zinc finger protein thing is really obscure outside the field.